# Arcgis online - how to create store locator

Tags: arcgis-online, google-maps, popup

I would be interested to know who to create store locator map in ArcGIS online, similar to that in Google Maps, where there is a left sidebar giving details of the locations with images/text attached to each location, and a weblink to click to obtain further information.  I can do this using the 'configure pop up command, but what I am interested is in creating the left sidebar.

Comment: Do you have ArcGIS Pro ?

Comment: Network Analyst extension is required for Calculating Locations https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/network-analyst/calculate-locations.htm